# SQL Where Clause with exclusions

Tags: where-clause

Hello I have a code where I am excluding some Catastrophe codes however I realized I shouldn't filter them all only the ones with those codes and the cause of loss a.CauseOfLoss <> '170 - All Other Liability'. How can I update this where clause?

```
WHERE (
    b.CatastropheCode <> '228' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '312' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '317' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '525' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '612' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '615' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '811' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '916' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '1012' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> '1113' and
    b.CatastropheCode <> 'MATT'
)
```

Comment: Uh, did you try cramming `a.CauseOfLoss <> '170 - All Other Liability' and ` to the front of the where clause?

Comment: Do I place it inside the parenthesis or outside?

Comment: Try both.  Good for the soul.